# Iterate class through div's, while page is loaded

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, loops

I have a seven portfolio items on a page, and only one of them has a class of "featured", as you may guess, that one is in focus. It's bigger and has more details.

Now, I want to change that class, to iterate through all portfolio items, after every  5sec. let's say. 
How would that be done? Bare in mind that I'm not that good with JS yet. Still learning, so I would appreciate your help on this one.

So, recap. I want when a visitor comes on page, for featured portfolio item to change, to go through all the items.

I'm interested in doing it with vanilla JS ES6, so no jQuery. But, if you know how it could've be done with jQuery as well, be free to post it.

Here's an example of the html for individual items.

```
<div class="portfolio-items">
                <!-- Portfolio item 1 -->
                <figure class="portfolio-item ">
                    <img src="img/portfolio-1.jpg" alt="portfolio-item">
                    <figcaption>
                        <h2 class="portfolio-title">Project Name</h2>
                        <p class="portfolio-desc">A short description could go right here</p>
                        <a href="#" class="portfolio-link">More info</a>
                    </figcaption>
                </figure>
```

class "featured" is being added to a figure tag.

Thanks :)

Comment: You need to lookup some basic JS suff like `setInterval()` and how to add/remove classes to elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can "collect" all relevant elements with [document.getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)
and add or remove a `css` class using the `classList.add` or `classList.remove` methods of each element.

You should keep track on what index you need to add the class (the next element in the collection) and what index of element you need to remove the class (the previous element in the collection).

As for the time iteration you can use the [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) function.

Here is a small running example:

```js
let currentIndex = 0;
const elements = document.getElementsByClassName('item');
setInterval(() => {
  const prevIndex = currentIndex === 0 ? elements.length - 1 : currentIndex - 1;
  const prevElement = elements[prevIndex];
  const nextElement = elements[currentIndex];
  prevElement && prevElement.classList.remove('active');
  nextElement && nextElement.classList.add('active');
  const nextIndex = currentIndex + 1;
  currentIndex = nextIndex === elements.length ? 0 : nextIndex
}, 1000);
```

```css
.item {
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 0 5px;
}

.active {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px #333;
  background-color: green;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">Item 1</div>
<div class="item">Item 2</div>
<div class="item">Item 3</div>
<div class="item">Item 4</div>
```

Comment: Ohh, wow. This was so helpful. It works. Thanks!
I have a general idea how this works, but I really need to learn my JS. :D